# My Ubuntu Laptop (Inspiron 14z) brightness function key does not work upon upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, brightness

My laptop with Ubuntu 12.04, everything worked fine including all hardware function keys, but when i upgraded to 14.04, the brightness 'Fn + F4/F5' stopped working.

I googled and followed a couple of suggestions, but nothing worked.

Can anybody tell me the way to work around it?